# Predictive Search In Array to filter Search Results

Tags: ios, arrays, json, uisearchbardelegate, predictive

I have an array with structure like this :

```
(
    {
    displayFlag = "<null>";
    displaySize = 0;
    name = "Faith Stretch Bracelets-Display Unit";
    price = "19.99";
    sku = "KARG-ACJE-100001-9999";
    status = received;
    upc = 722950218860;
},
    {
    displayFlag = "<null>";
    displaySize = 0;
    name = "Faith Stretch Bracelets";
    price = "19.99";
    sku = "KARG-ACJE-100002-9999";
    status = "received,created";
    upc = 722950218867;
}
)
```

I am doing predictive search this way and unable to get results:

```
filteredFmdbArray =
        [[fmdbArrayAdjust[i] allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd]%@",text]];
```

Here :

- fmdbArrayAdjust : array which contains whole response data.
- text : input entered by user in search bar.
- filteredFmdbArray : nsarray in which i want to get all filtered results.

How can I modify my search statement in order to get results. I want to get search results on the basis of "name".

Comment: @"SELF.name contains[cd]%@",text]"?

Comment: Using above statement it is throwing error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSTaggedPointerString 0xa0014038006300a8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.' @Larme

Comment: Remove the `allValues`

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. @Larme